# Does 1,957 centimorgans indicate half-siblings?

Tags: dna, autosomal-dna

I have recently had a DNA test and have a shared match of 1957 over 50 segments with one of the matches.  They are not interested at the moment in communicating.
I was brought up as an only child, so it cannot be a niece or nephew.  It cannot be a grandparent as they are not alive and haven't been for along time.

Is it likely that this person is a half-sibling?

If so how do I find out whether it was my mother's child or father's child?

Comment: 1,957cM gives you the same possibilities as the duplicate: https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4/1957

Comment: If we assume that your results do indicate a half-sibling then your second question should be researched/asked as a new question.  Have any of your maternal/paternal aunts/uncles/first cousins tested?